# SQLAlchemy scalar() returns string for DATETIME('now') with SQLite

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have the following code:

```py
if settings.DATABASE_URL.startswith("sqlite"):  
    CURRENT_TIME_QUERY = "SELECT DATETIME('now')" 
else:
    CURRENT_TIME_QUERY = "SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

timestamp = session.execute(CURRENT_TIME_QUERY).scalar()
```

When I'll run this code against `MySQL`, the `timestamp` will be a `datetime` object, but in the case of `SQLite` I get a string with the actual timestamp. Does the SQLAlchemy handles these cases differently, or is it the query's fault? I'd like to always have a `datetime` object.

Comment: SQLite does not have a datetime data type, it stores datetimes as strings.

Comment: Note that `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` works for SQLite too: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4408d20db5baa1e72161b04c6ff942ce

Comment: @forpas - right, it works here, but not in migrations for the `server_default`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a bare query like yours, SQLAlchemy is just returning what the driver (DBAPI layer) gives it. The MySQL driver (e.g., mysqldb) is returning a `datetime.datetime` object, while the SQLite driver is returning a `<class 'str'>`. As noted in the comments to the question and in the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times.

Note that if you have an ORM object or a Core `Table` with columns defined as `sqlalchemy.DateTime` then the sqlite dialect will convert the returned string values to `datetime` for you:

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql("CREATE TABLE thing (id int primary key, dt datetime)")
    conn.exec_driver_sql("INSERT INTO thing (id, dt) VALUES (1, '2021-09-02 08:50:12')")


class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = "thing"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    dt = Column(DateTime)


with Session(engine) as session:
    result = session.execute(select(Thing.dt)).scalar()
    print(repr(result))  # datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 2, 8, 50, 12)
```

However, for a plain query you will have to check if the returned value is a `str` and convert it to `datetime` yourself.